# Cannot handle VBA error when running consecutive VBA subs from a main sub

Tags: excel, vba

I have a module that when it runs , it runs concecutive subs. There is a case when something goes wrong in a sub. So I want to exit sub and continue with the following line in the main sub which is like the following

```
Sub MasterMacro()
Call EnableTimer

Call getMetaData1
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Call saveTableToCSV

Call getMetaData2
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Call saveTableToCSV

Call getMetaData3
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Call saveTableToCSV

Call getMetaData4
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Call saveTableToCSV

End Sub
```

Can I place a general error in each sub to Exit sub?
If I exit sub it will continue in the next line of Main Sub?
Most errors I have so far are

Error on getting data from webpage

Error on connecting to webpage

Error on Timeout

Comment: I'd suggest to read on [Error-Handling](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/). Anything else depends IMHO how you want to handle the Errors: deal with them, just skip them (not recommended), ...

Comment: I just did and I am testing it by adding a label with exit sub in each sub

Comment: You are a fast reader. I am impressed ;-)

Comment: There are random errors I guess. There is the case I run the master sub and I get error on getMetaData3 sub so everything stops. If I run it seperately its working fine

Comment: I'd trap the error in each sub but incidentally, I'd change the sub to a function that returns a Boolean which means continue or not.  Catastrophic errors which mean a a program abort would be signalled by returning false.  Recoverable errors which do not prejudice following steps can be signalled by returning true.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a plan for collecting the data which is different from yours in that it collects all 4 data in an array and processes that array only after a specific time (e.g. 10 seconds, adjustable). If complete data are available earlier they could be written earlier, and if this is the case you might limit the scraping to specific intervals - all things which are so much harder to do while you try and process each single datum individually.

```
Sub RecordData()

    ' create an array with 1 element for each of the 4 data you wish to record
    Dim Arr(1 To 4) As Variant
    Dim TimeOut As Single
    Dim Tmp As String
    Dim Done As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer                            ' loop counter

    TimeOut = Timer + 10                        ' allow 10 seconds to complete scraping
    Do While Not Done
        Done = True
        For i = 1 To 4
            If IsEmpty(Arr(i)) Then
                Tmp = GetMetaData(i)            ' get the scraped string
                Done = Len(Tmp)                 ' sets Done to False if Tmp is ""
            End If
        Next i
        If Timer > TimeOut Then Exit Do         ' end the loop on time-out
    Loop

    ' Now write the contents of Arr to your workbook
    ' It may be complete or not.
End Sub

Private Function GetMetaData(DataID As Integer) As String

    ' DataID should mark the difference between your
    ' procedures GetMwetaDat1 thru 4.
    ' If you don't know how to merge the 4 procedures into one
    ' on that basis, the following setup could be used.
    GetMetaData = Application.Run("GetMetaData" & DataID)

    ' The GetMetaData# procedures must be created as functions
    ' which return nothing if an error occurred.
    ' capture the error with
    On Error Resume Next
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        ' GetMetaData# = [Scraped value]
    End If
    Err.Clear
    ' The above setup will return an empty string ("")
    ' if an error occurred in the scraping
End Function
```

Comment: You use `GetMetaData#`, but your function returns `String`